# Login Module doesn't work

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

I am developing an android application with help of:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7Z4GVFaT4A&list=PLe60o7ed8E-TztoF2K3y4VdDgT6APZ0ka&index=4

When I reciprocated the same tutorial, the application worked absolutely fine. Then I modulated the application to fit into my application idea. The Registration was successful and stored data into db as expected.
But facing issue in LoginActivity.

Expected way the app should proceed: When I click blogin button, it should validate the user stored in db and open corresponding AdminViewActivity.

What actually happening is that when i click the button blogin, nothing happens. The table name is "allusers" and already contains values. I type the same values while logging in through my application.

Please help me find where I could have gone wrong. Thanks in advance.

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.ablo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final Button bregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bregister);
        final Button blogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin);
        final EditText etusername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        final EditText etpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etpassword);


        bregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }
        });



       blogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                final String username=etusername.getText().toString();
                final String password=etpassword.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener= new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success= jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if(success){
                                String name= jsonResponse.getString("name");
                                Intent i=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,AdminViewActivity.class);

                                i.putExtra("name",name);

                                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(i);


                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry",null).create().show();

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                LoginRequest loginRequest=new LoginRequest(username,password,responseListener );
                RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**LoginRequest.java**

```
package com.example.android.ablo;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by User on 21-01-2018.
 */

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static  final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://ablo.000webhostapp.com/AbloLogin.php";
    private Map<String,String> params;

    public LoginRequest( String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null );
        params= new HashMap<>();

        params.put("username",username);

        params.put("password",password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

**AbloLogin.php**

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id4335430_ablo_users", "wontreveal", "id4335430_ablo_users");



    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $password = $_POST["password"];



    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM allusers WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);



    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $allusersID, $name,  $username, $password);



    $response = array();

    $response["success"] = false;  



    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){

        $response["success"] = true;  

        $response["name"] = $name;

        $response["username"] = $username;

        $response["password"] = $password;

    }



    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

**AdminViewActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.ablo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class AdminViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_view);

        final Button badduser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.badduser);
        final Button bmanageusers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bmanageusers);

        final TextView tvadmin =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvadmin);

        Intent i= getIntent();
        String name= i.getStringExtra("name");

        String message= name+ "'s Admin View";
        tvadmin.setText(message);

        badduser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(AdminViewActivity.this, CreateUserActivity.class);
                AdminViewActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        bmanageusers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(AdminViewActivity.this, ManageUsersActivity.class);
                AdminViewActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```